# Installing PHPExcel for Phabricator

Tags: google-compute-engine, php.ini, bitnami

I have installed `Phabricator` using the official `Bitnami` image on `Google Compute Engine`. It's working great, but when I try to use `export to excel` button in `Maniphest`, it shows the following error -

> Excel Export Not Configured    This system does not have PHPExcel
>   installed. This software component is required to export tasks to
>   Excel. Have your system administrator install it from:
>
> https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel
>
> Your PHP "include_path" needs to be updated to include the PHPExcel
>   Classes directory.

So I git cloned the PHPExcel library to `~/apps/PHPExcel` directory. The `php.ini` file was at `/opt/bitnami/php/etc/php.ini`. I opened it and added the following path in the include_path section -

> include_path=".:/opt/bitnami/php/lib/php:~/apps/PHPExcel/Classes:~/apps/PHPExcel"
>   ;include_path = ".;c:\php\includes" ; PHP's default setting for
>   include_path is ".;/path/to/php/pear" ; Enables or disables file
>   search in include_path optimization

And as per the [instructions](https://docs.bitnami.com/google/apps/phabricator/#how-to-modify-the-allowed-limit-for-uploaded-files) from `Bitnami`, I restarted the server using following commands -

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart php-fpm
```

But it's still giving the same error and telling me that `PHPExcel` is still not installed.

Am I missing something here? If yes, can you please provide the exact way to use the `Export to Excel` feature?

Comment: Hi, Bitnami Engineer here. Please note that ~/ means the home folder of the user who runs the commands, as Apache and PHP-FPM runs as 'daemon', it doesn't mean /home/bitnami so I suggest you clone the repository in a folder inside /opt/bitnami/apps/phabricator or a similar path, set the proper permissions for daemon to read/write it and modify the include_path settings accordingly. Regards, Jota

Comment: @JotaMartos Thanks a lot for your response. I moved the PHPExcel to phabricator folder and changed the php.ini and it started to work. Can you add it as an answer, so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1):

Bitnami Engineer here.

Please note that `~/` means the home folder of the user who runs the commands, as Apache and PHP-FPM runs as 'daemon', it doesn't mean `/home/bitnami` so I suggest you clone the repository in a folder inside `/opt/bitnami/apps/phabricator` or a similar path, set the proper permissions for daemon to read/write it and modify the include_path settings accordingly.